# Unused indexing's effect over performance

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

In my website, I don't create users. Users are/were created in a different system, that I have no access to.

There they used a Userid = VARCHAR(50)

On my side, I keep a very simple table, something like

```
 UserId VARCHAR(50)
 Employer VARCHAR(4)
 UserSpecificField VARCHAR(8)
 DateWhenItWasAddedToOurSystem DATETIME
```

Upon logging in to my system, I just make a simple SYNC, so I have everybody in my system too.
I got 2000 records in this table.

Question:

I know that indexing is good, and it should be used. I was thinking about adding an indexed column to this table, but I am not sure if it would help.

Is adding an index going to help performance even if you don't use that column to anything? Because everywhere I use the USER, I am forced to use the user's VARCHAR(50) ID to make SQL JOIN based on.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have an index on `UserId` or is `UserId` a primary key? With 2000 entries an index will not boost your application dramatically. However, when joining or querying for a column an index will help. There are other dependencies: which other columns are used from the User table, how often will the User table be updated and so on. BTW an index on a column never used is only a performance burden for insert, update and delete.

Comment: at this point I have no index at all on this table. But there is an other table with 1 mil records that is joined up with this one using the UserId Varchar(50) col

Comment: Under these circumstances an index (or better a primary key constraint) on `UserId` would help to avoid a full table scan. Before adding the index test the query plan, add the index after that and test the query plan again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting beside small table size, there's no point in adding an index on UserId in table of this structure. Notice that this column (given that varchar(50) field will be filled in average 50%), this single column will be 70% of table size. 
So db engine would have to scan the index first (which has almost the size of an enitre table), and then seek for records in a table itsef. This operation would be more resource-intensive than just scanning a table. I'm pretty sure that optimizer will not use an index at all. Test it yourself.
The only option in my opinion is adding a clustered index, which will in effect "sort" your table by UserId, making queries run faster, and not making any overhead by building aditional structure (ie "normal" index). I assume that update operation is not perform very often.

```
create unique clustered index idxCLU__userid on <your_table_name>(UserId )
```